# Об употреблении "ибо" вместо "тогда и только тогда, когда"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Разумно ли использовать слово "ибо" вместо словосочетания "тогда и только тогда, когда"?

Пример (замещения "тогда и только тогда, когда" на "ибо")

- "Три больше, чем два, тогда и только тогда, когда два меньше, чем три."
- "Три больше, чем два, ибо два меньше, чем три."

Answer (score 2):

Хо-хо, опять... )))

Неразумно, ибо "ибо" уже занято и означает оно отнюдь не "тогда и только тогда".

Точно так же и "ежели" занято.

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы Niemand кричал: "Занято!"

Answer (score 0):

В первом варианте : Тогда и только тогда, когда=если( т.е. при условии). Во втором варианте, вы констатируете факт, в этом случае ибо=зн. союзам: потому что, так как.

Вы правильно поняли. Вот значение: ТОГДА, нареч.
1.
В то время, не сейчас, не теперь. Он т. был ещё ребёнком. Было холодно, т. и простудился. * Я тогда моложе, я лучше, кажется, была (Пушкин). //
После того, что произошло или произойдёт. Сделаешь уроки - т. и гулять пойдёшь. Встретимся - т. и поговорим.
2.
***В таком случае, при таких условиях, обстоятельствах. Устал, т. отдохни. Раз согласны, т. начинайте. Не нервничай, т. всё получится***. < Тогда как, союз. 1.
Выражает противопоставление. Он работал, тогда как ты всё время бездельничал. Мать прекрасно играет на скрипке, тогда как дочь лишена музыкального слуха. -2.
Несмотря на то, что; хотя. Её отругали, тогда как она ни в чём не виновата. Его расхваливают, тогда как музыкант он очень посредственный.

ИБО, союз. Книжн.
Употр. в придаточном предложении причины, соответствует по зн. союзам: *потому что, так как.* Создать язык невозможно, ибо его творит народ.
Большой толковый словарь русского языка. Гл. ред. С. А. Кузнецов.
Первое издание: СПб.: Норинт, 1998.
Публикуется в авторской редакции 2009 года.( Словарь есть на Грамота.ру).

Comment: Если я правильно Вас понял:

1) предложение "Три больше, чем два, тогда и только тогда, когда два меньше, чем три." и предложение "Три больше, чем два, если (т.е. при условии) два меньше, чем три." тождественны по смыслу,

2) предложение "Три больше, чем два, ибо два меньше, чем три." и предложение "Три больше, чем два, потому что (т.е. так как) два меньше, чем три." тождественны по смыслу,

3) предложение "Три больше, чем два, тогда и только тогда, когда два меньше, чем три." отличается по смыслу от предложения "Три больше, чем два, ибо два больше, чем три.".

Comment: 1. Спасибо за Ваши пояснения.

2. Не исключено, что словосочетание "тогда и только тогда, когда" можно воспринять как словосочетание "в то время и только в то время, когда".

Comment: Первое утверждение неверно.